# Script always throws an error if CREATE/ALTER is not first statement

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am getting an error when I try to execute the script that is given at end of this post. My requirement is to check for procedure's existence, then drop it if it exists and finally create the procedure.

How would I do this using a single script file?

> Procedure Proc_GenerateTestData. 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch. SQL2.sql 12 1

The SQL script that always throws above error is as below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Proc_GenerateTestData', 'p') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_GenerateTestData
END


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_GenerateTestData @numberOfRecords INT = 100
AS
  --drop table #temp1

  DECLARE @currentTime AS TIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME);
  DECLARE @currentWorkShiftDate AS DATETIME = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME);

  DECLARE @startTime TIME,
          @lastShiftStartTime TIME;

  DECLARE @tenantId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT TOP (1)
    Tenants.Id
  FROM Tenants
  ORDER BY Tenants.Id ASC);
  DECLARE @workshiftId INT,
  @lastShiftStartDate DATETIME;
  --more statements for this procedure follow
```

Comment: As the error *clearly* says - the `CREATE PROCEDURE` **must be** the first statement in a query batch. This is **not** the case here, since you have the check for the `DROP` before .... you need to change your script so that the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement **is** the first in the query batch - if you're running this in SQL Server Management Studio, just add a  `GO` delimiter before the `CREATE`....

Comment: Can you post this as an answer? It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error *clearly* says - the `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be the first statement in a query batch.

This is not the case here, since you have the check for the `DROP` before hand.

You need to change your script so that the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement is really the **first** in the query batch. If you're running this in SQL Server Management Studio, just add a `GO` delimiter before the `CREATE`.